# How to check if a paypal payment is completed or not?

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I'm using paypal IPN. Now All is working fine. And I'm getting `VERIFIED` status. but how to check `payment_status` is `completed` or not? thanks

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
 }
```

There is no such variable called `$_POST['payment_status']`

```
Array
(
[txn_type] => subscr_signup
[subscr_id] => I-LDEC0BD3UYL7
[last_name] => User
[residence_country] => US
[mc_currency] => USD
[item_name] => Alice's Weekly Digest
[business] => savife_1314264698_biz@gmail.com
[amount3] => 35.00
[recurring] => 0
[verify_sign] => AkLS8p39eNu16-x1.zjarjEI8cwRAJTbKtOMbm2NinNXnj79aqkEZ5it
[payer_status] => verified
[test_ipn] => 1
[payer_email] => savife_1314427849_per@gmail.com
[first_name] => Test
[receiver_email] => savife_1314264698_biz@gmail.com
[payer_id] => SWCUEE3GNET7A
[reattempt] => 1
[item_number] => DIG Weekly
[subscr_date] => 00:02:52 Aug 27, 2011 PDT
[charset] => windows-1252
[notify_version] => 3.2
[period3] => 1 M
[mc_amount3] => 35.00
[auth] => _XXXXXXX   [form_charset] => UTF-8
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to echo `$_POST['payment_status']`. payment_status is a ipn variable sent by paypal to your ipn script. if payment is completed it will print completed else not.

following code shows the Validity of IPN, not payment.

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// IPN VERIFIED
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// IPN INVALID
}
```

EDIT 1:

$_POST array is split here, you do not need to split it yourself:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
```

just take values of variables in the follwoing format:

```
// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
```

you will see that there is a variable posted by paypal named `payment_status`.

try to add this line echo `$_POST['payment_status'];` to your ipn page and see what does it prints, if it will print completed, that means your payment status is completed sucessfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm printing the whole array using. `print_r($_GET)`. If i print this like `print_r($_POST)`. Its print empty array.

Comment: there is no variable called `$_POST['payment_status']`. `$_POST['item_name']',`$_POST['item_number']',etc are exists but not `$_POST['payment_status']`

Comment: did you tried echoing it. I am using this variable. Please echo it. It exists. it is one of very important variables.

Comment: Yes I tried echoing it. I'm not getting any message. all others variable exists... please help me I'm stuck

Comment: thats strange. post your script here. i'll check it.

Comment: here is a link. http://dpaste.com/603644/ please help me. I'm getting mad.........

Comment: did you enabled ipn in your paypal sandbox account?

Comment: No I have not see any option related to ipn. Can you give me link ?

Comment: Login to your paypal sandbox account, then on the right side you will see a tab my accounts. click on it and it will show you all of your test accounts you've created in your sandbox mode. select any of your merchant (seller) account. and then click login. it will login you to your merchant account. now click on the profile tab. it will show you a new window. with three panels. on the right panel, there will be two links, website payment preferences and instant payment notification. click first IPN and you'll see a window. in which it will ask you to enable your ipn and enter ipn url.

Comment: you are echoing payment_status before all other variables. echo it after $payer_email.

Comment: This should not be marked as a correct answer. See the other comments. The OP is receiving a SUBSCR_SIGNUP. No payment information is associated with a subscription signup notification. There will be a SUBSCR_PAYMENT notification that contains the payment information.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you're not seeing the 'payment_status' variable is because Paypal doesn't include that in the response for subscriptions.

For subscriptions, you should check

```
if ($_POST['txn_type'] == "subscr_ signup") {
  //do whatever
}
```

Other options are: 
subscr_ cancel, subscr_ modify, subscr_payment, subscr_ failed, and subscr_eot

See the Summary of subscription variables on this page for more details:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB0901HT

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's the only one that answers the problem - which isn't very clear from PayPal's docs.

Answer (score 1):

look at the examples scripts provided by paypal

...

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        if ($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed") {
```

...